# Attempt to invoke virtual method on null object reference (JAVA, AS)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat

When running this script:

```
    package com.example.benjamin.labb3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.Window;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Main extends Activity {

    DrawView drawView;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        setContentView(drawView);
    }

    @Override public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        drawView.resume();
    }

    @Override public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        drawView.pause();
    }

    public class  DrawView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
        Thread gameloop = null;
        SurfaceHolder surface;
        volatile boolean running = false;
        AssetManager assets = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
        Bitmap incect[];
        int frame = 0;

        public DrawView(Context context){
            super(context);
            surface = getHolder();
            assets = context.getAssets();
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

            incect = new Bitmap[2];

            try {
                for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++){
                    String fileName = "Incect"+Integer.toString(n+1)+".png";
                    InputStream istream = assets.open(fileName);
                    incect[n] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istream,null,options);
                    istream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void resume() {
            running = true;
            gameloop = new Thread(this);
            gameloop.start();
        }

        public void pause() {
            running = false;
            boolean retry = true;
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    gameloop.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e){}
            }
        }

        @Override public void run(){
            while (running){

                if(!surface.getSurface().isValid())
                    continue;
                Canvas canvas = surface.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(85,107,47));
                canvas.drawBitmap(incect[frame],0,0,null);
                surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                frame ++;
                if (frame > 1){
                    frame = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error message:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-106
>                                                                             Process: com.example.benjamin.labb3, PID: 2169
>                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                 at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1269)
>                                                                                 at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1325)
>                                                                                 at com.example.benjamin.labb3.Main$DrawView.run(Main.java:97)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

So i navigate to the line 97 that the error was in (which is in the last method called run()):

line 97:    `frame = 0;`

The error log says that its "null" so i check if frame is declared and it turns out that it already is, so how can i get an error saying it is null?

I declared it here:

```
public class  DrawView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
        Thread gameloop = null;
        SurfaceHolder surface;
        volatile boolean running = false;
        AssetManager assets = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
        Bitmap incect[];
        int frame = 0;
```

Or is the log reffering to something else? I am currently following a tutorial on how to set up a sprite animation so i dont really understand the log that well yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`incect[frame]` could be `null`.check if the `bitmap` exists at that particular position in the array.

Comment: Turned out the png file "incect" was spelled with an uppercase i, so i changed that to "Incect" instead and it worked!